# scala error: type arguments do not conform to class type parameter bounds [X >: A,Y >: A]

Tags: scala, generics, subtype, subtyping

I am trying to define a class with type boundaries.

```
trait External[T]{
  def deserialize( bytes: Array[Byte] ) : T
}

trait A

case class Hi(i: Int) extends A

class Foo[X >: A] extends External[X] {
   def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]) : X = Hi(1)
}

scala> new Foo[Hi]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
  <console>:14: error: type arguments [Hi] do not conform to class Foo's type parameter bounds [X >: A]
       val res2 =
           ^
```

What am I doing wrong ? how can I solve it ?
**EDIT:** 
If I will try to revert the bound Foo[X <: A, Y <:A] then I will get the following error:

```
 scala> class Foo[X <: A]{
      def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): X = Hi(1)
      }
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Hi


required: X
          def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): X =Hi(1)
                                                    ^
```

I can solve it by doing :

```
class Foo[X <: A]{
          def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): X = a.asInstanceOf[X]
          }
```

Is that the idiomatic way or is there a better one ?

Comment: Your type bounds are incorrect. If you want to only allow types that extend `A` then you need to use `[X <: A, Y <: A]`

Comment: The question is still not clear. What is `a` and what is type `Y` for? Can you clean up this question to give complete example that shows the error you are trying to fix. It is also better to avoid using REPL for this kind of thing as it does not always work the way that you expect.

Comment: @Tim the `Y` is indeed redundant and is an old code that I cleaned now

Comment: What about `a`?

Comment: @igx Where does `a` come from? - Also, from the error it says that it is of type `A` but you said your return type is an `X` which should be a subtype of `A`, you can not _(safely)_ cast an arbitrary instance of `A` to `X`.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks ! I done another round of cleanup, sorry about that

Comment: @igx Again, the problem is that you said you will return an `X` _(Any kind of X)_ but you are returning a `Hi`. You can not guarantee that `Hi <:< X`. For example, lets suppose another user defines `case class Hey(s: String) extends A` and then it tries to use `Foo[Hey]` and you return a `Hi`, everything will crash. - I believe this can be easily solved using **typeclasses**, but the question is not clear. Mind open a new question explaining your boarder problem?

Answer (score 0):

Right now your type constraints say "for types X and Y which are superclasses of A". If you are wanting subclasses of A then you need to change your type bounds to `[X <: A, Y <: A]`. Here's an example that compiles:

```
trait A
trait B extends A
trait C extends A
case class Foo[X <: A, Y <: A](x: X, y: Y)
case class Hi(i: Int) extends A

Foo(Hi(1), Hi(2))
```

Comment: please see the edited example. my prev example was over simplified

Answer (score 0):

`class Foo[X >: A, Y >: A]` is expecting supertypes of `A` but `Hi` is a subtype of `A` since it extends it.

```
class Foo[X <: A, Y <: A]
```

is the right way

Comment: Thanks, I oversimplified my example. please see the edited example